# player not moving to requested position - unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

my goal is when in radius of a door, when you press down you move scene and get moved to the position of the door but no matter what i try, my player wont move there. any ideas?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public string sceneToWarpTo;
    public string doorScene;
    
    public float doorLocationX;
    public float doorLocationY;

    public GameObject player;

    private float x;
    private float y;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        x = player.transform.position.x;
        y = player.transform.position.y;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
     IEnumerator LoadFixThing()
    {
        
        //yield on a new YieldInstruction that waits for 5 seconds.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        
    }
    public void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D coll) {
        if (coll.tag == "Player"){
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
                Debug.Log("Enter Door");
                Debug.Log("warping to " + sceneToWarpTo + " from " + doorScene);
                SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToWarpTo);
                LoadFixThing();
                player.transform.position = new Vector2(doorLocationX,  doorLocationY); 
                Debug.Log("player pos: " + player.transform.position);
                Debug.Log("door pos: " + this.transform.position);
                Debug.Log(player.name);
                

            }

        }
    }
}
```

i dont really know what more to say but it keeps saying my question requires more info so thank you for reading my question :)

Comment: Does the logged position match the desired one?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... shouldn't you call SceneManager.Loadscene after moving the player? Try that first..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening a new scene, the current player object is destroyed along with the previous scene. If you want to persist it, you can use [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)